# Unable to work on git after installation

Tags: git

I have installed git on my desktop and I am getting this error when i try to execute any git command on git 'C:\ProgramData/Git/config' has a dubious owner

Also as this is my temporary desktop, I am not working with the administrator account in this desktop. Could anyone help on this issue.

Can I delete config file and then try to install it again

Answer (score 0):

We had also this issue.

If the file C:\ProgramData/Git/config doesn't exists, then create it with the following content:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

In your case also the folder Git didn't exist.

Comment: I suppose an empty file would suffice, all these settings have their defaults

Comment: Good one, that could work indeed